# Linking with CrystalReports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I'm doing a report in C # using CrystalReports, the problem is I can not link the tables, because when the procedure does not recognize the foreign key are only two tables, this is the sql code:

```
create table proveedores(
    id_proveedor int identity(1,1) not null,
    nombre_empresa nvarchar(100),
    direccion nvarchar(100),
    telefono int,
    fecha_registro_proveedor nvarchar(100),
    constraint pk_proveedores primary key(id_proveedor)
);

create table productos(
    id_producto int identity(1,1) not null,
    nombre_producto nvarchar(100),
    descripcion nvarchar(100),
    precio int,
    id_proveedor int,
    fecha_registro nvarchar(100),
    constraint pk_productos primary key(id_producto),
    constraint fk_productos foreign key (id_proveedor) references proveedores(id_proveedor) 
);

insert into proveedores(nombre_empresa,direccion,telefono,fecha_registro_proveedor) 
    values('empresa 1','calle 1',4975034,'2016-04-02');

insert into proveedores(nombre_empresa,direccion,telefono,fecha_registro_proveedor) 
    values('empresa 2','calle 2',4646891,'2016-03-06');

insert into proveedores(nombre_empresa,direccion,telefono,fecha_registro_proveedor) 
    values('empresa 3','calle 3',4646891,'2016-08-21');



insert into productos(nombre_producto,descripcion,precio,id_proveedor,fecha_registro) 
    values('producto 1','descripcion 1',200,1,'2016-03-01');

insert into productos(nombre_producto,descripcion,precio,id_proveedor,fecha_registro) 
    values('producto 2','descripcion 2',400,2,'2016-01-06');

insert into productos(nombre_producto,descripcion,precio,id_proveedor,fecha_registro) 
    values('producto 3','descripcion 3',500,3,'2016-08-02');
```

I'm trying to link the products (productos) and vendors (proveedores) to display the products with their data and the vendor name table.

The problem is that it does not show the names of the suppliers when already made the corresponding links.

[image]

Images in VS 2012 :

[image]

[image: Result]

How fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `nombre_empresa` field in your report, not `id_proveedor`. If you conceptually linked one table to another via `join` it doesn't magically replace reference to ID field in another table with relevant values.